# Brute Force attack on Symmetric Cryptography

Tags: symmetric

If I have a specific key length say 4 and a given ciphertext, how do I use `str.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-#\\.\\!\\;\\,\\(\\)\\/%&\\s]*$"))` to find a key in order to get the plaintext.

So far I have a class for generating strings of a fixed size:

```
class Get {
char[] alphabet; // stores all possible letters as a character array
int keyLength;   // how long the key is
int x = 0;       // internal count of the number of strings generated
int max;         // maximum number of strings to be generated

/*
 * keyLength: length of the key strings to be generated
 */
Guess(int keyLength) {
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();  // use English's  
    this.keyLength = keyLength;                             // save key length
    this.max = (int) Math.pow(alphabet.length, keyLength) - 1;  // maximum number of guesses
}

/*
 * Generate a new string of keyLength long
 * Returns null if all strings have been generated
 */
String gen() {
    String ret = null;

    if(x < max) {
        char[] c = new char[keyLength];
        int[] y = toDigits(x);
        for(int i = 0; i<keyLength; i++) {
            c[i] = alphabet[y[i]];
        }
        ret = new String(c);
        x = x + 1;
    }
    return ret;
}

/*
 * Convert a number x into digits using the size of the alphabet as base
 */
int[] toDigits(int x) {
    int[] ret = new int[keyLength]; 
    for(int i = 1; i <= keyLength; i++) {
        ret[keyLength - i] = x % alphabet.length; 
        x = x / alphabet.length;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I want to learn how to write a method that will go through all possible keys, trying them to see if the ciphertext is a plaintext, and if it is print the message and the key it found

Answer (score 0):

One method is to calculate frequency of letters in candidate plaintext and see if matches with frequency for plaintext language. For English this [table](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html) can be used.

For more detailed description see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/developing-algorithm-for-detecting-plain-text-via-frequency-analysis?newreg=6d21f0f39836419faeb3c774414be3f8)

Candidates can be then checked against a dictionary to validate that words make sense, or dictionary approach can be used directly.